# Count & Search the Data on DataTable

Tags: c#, database

I have four columns name `SrNo,RollNo,Name,Age` in my datatable and corresponding values as

```
SrNo ,Roll No,Name,Age
1,      1,     ABC, 20
2,      2,     DEF, 22
3,      3,     ABC, 25
```

I want search how many different a names are present & their count.

Please suggest

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to do this would probably be with LINQ (IMO, anyway):

```
var groups = table.AsEnumerable()
                  .GroupBy(x => x.Field<string>("Name"))
                  .Select(g => new { Name = g.Key, Count = g.Count() });
```

That's assuming you really do have the data in a `DataTable`. If it's actually still in the database, you can use a similar LINQ to SQL query:

```
var groups = dataContext.GroupBy(x => x.Name)
                        .Select(g => new { Name = g.Key, Count = g.Count() });
```

Actually you could use an overload of `GroupBy` to do it all in one method call:

```
var groups = dataContext.GroupBy(x => x.Name,
                                 (key, group) => new { Name = key, 
                                                       Count = group.Count() });
```

Comment: Nice solution,But while implementing it i am getting error on x as it says x cannot be used as it is already used in parent.

Comment: @user373083: If you've already got a variable named `x` elsewhere in the method, just change wherever I've got `x` to something else, e.g. `z`.

Answer (score 1):

```
select count(1) as cnt, Name from mytable group by Name
```

Answer (score 0):

Write a SQL query that creates this summary and execute it using ADO.NET.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use sql server. Below is the answer

```
Select Name, count(Name)
From YourTableNamew 
Group by Name
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT column_name) FROM table_name group by column_name
```

Comment: Group by is doing the job of Distinct. So we should omit it from the query.